# String.split() method - order of token in the returned String array

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I am working on an application where I have to deal with a custom variable **`aVar`**-

```
String aVar = price/barcode/area1/true  // varName/varType/varScope/tracable
```

There may be some other attribute added to **`aVar`** seperated by a ('/').
To get `varName, varType, varScope` etc I have to do the following things, please see the code below -

```
String[] token = aVar.split("/");  

String varName = token[0];
String varType = token[1];
String varScope = token[2];
String traceable = token[3];
```

Here you can see the `varName` is taken from `token[0]` which is `price`, `varType` is taken from `token[1]` which is 'barcode' and so on. Here I am assuming - after splitting `varName` always be in token[0], `varType` always be in token[1] and so on.
Now my question is that - Does the `String` array returned by the `split()` method always contain the `String` token in a order by which they are appeared (price-->barcode-->area1-->true)?

I have tested this several times with some few input and found the order maintained. But I am not sure will it be **ALWAYS** true for a **VERY LONG** string.

Comment: YES it is an ordered array from the first to the last value of the source string.

Comment: I don't see how that code even compiles - there's no overload for `String.split` accepting a `char`. Do you mean `aVar.split("/")`?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, great finding.  It was a typo (which I have fixed just now) comes from the being accustomed to java script split( ) version for char.

Comment: This is why it's useful to create a short but complete program, compile and run it, then copy and paste *that* into the question. It avoids problems like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) here:

```
The substrings in the array are in the order in which they occur in this string.
```

watch for the line `The substrings in the array are in the order in which they occur in this string.` in the link.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're actually calling [`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), that method's documentation includes:

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

That method's documentation includes:

> The array returned by this method contains each substring of this string that is terminated by another substring that matches the given expression or is terminated by the end of the string. **The substrings in the array are in the order in which they occur in this string.** If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string.

(Emphasis mine.)

So yes, they'll be returned in order, guaranteed.

Answer (score 3):

> Does the String array returned by the split() method always contain the String token in a order by which they are appeared (price-->barcode-->area1-->true)?

In a word - yes.
`String.split` maintains the order of the inputted string.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) the result has an order:

> The substrings in the array are in the order in which they occur in
>   this string